# Upgrading jailbroken phone while maintaining tweaks using iFile

Tags: upgrade, jailbreak, ios

I was just curious if I copied all of the contents of iFile from like the root folder, and then upgraded my iphone's ios version, rejailbroke my iphone, and redownloaded iFile, if I copied the contents into the new iFile would it basically be like it saved my previous jailbreak?

I know the current iOS version doesn't have a jailbreak out, I'm just curious if per say this would work?

Comment: No it wouldn't work

Comment: IronCraftMan is right! Does not work (:

Answer (score 1):

> @IronCraftMan No it wouldn't work

Is correct you would be better off making a backup with iTunes and using some tool to save your SHSH blobs so you can downgrade, there are some jailbreak backup utilities but I cannot vouch for the validity or security of them.